# Excel - value in one cell populates cell in next column with certain data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image: Example1]

In Excel, on sheet "Customer Gift Pack Log" - see image, when a number/dollar value is put in column C "Price Of Build", that the next cell across in column D (Gift Pack No.) will populate with the relevant table/drop down (Displayed on next sheet "Gift Packs" - See image). This would allow the use user to have the relevant pack name shown in the d column and when they click the drop down would display items that go in the pack.

If this can't be done, how do I simply make the cell in column D just show the relevant number based on the value ranges i.e.. (1) for $2K - $5K or (2) for $5K - $20K and so on?

I also would like columns E & F's cells to fill color or highlight if the pack selected should contains those items so the user knows to find and input customer size.

Hope that makes sense. And Thank you to anyone taking the time to offer help or input.

[image: Example2]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your question should be divided into 3 questions at least. Because you are asking for a wholesale solution.
Now, answering your main question (as I think it is) regarding displaying the pack number as per amount that is spent.

1. It is a good practice in Excel to have reference lists on separate sheet and that is what I would advise you in your situation. You can change data at your Gift Packs sheet or create new sheet (I usually call them just "i" for "information"). The data there should be structured as a "Flat table", meaning just simple lists, so that it can be used later with such functions as xlookup. Simply put in your situation: Column A for Pack name, B for starting amount (lover one), C for description of the content.
   [flat table for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xFJg.jpg)
2. At your Cust.GiftPackLog sheet in column D use this great though old and forgotten function LOOKUP. What is great about this function is that it looks through all the vector and returns the smaller one closest result. Though it is important that you sort your gift packs in ascending order.

   ```
   =LOOKUP(C2;i!$B$2:$B$9;i!$A$2:$A$9)
   ```

Change the syntaxes from ";" to "," depending on your system language settings.
There are other ways to achieve this result, but I find Lookup formula the best in such cases.

If you have office 365 then you can use the new XLOOKUP formula instead, which is a must-know formula that replaces all the LOOKUP, VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP formulas and does much more.

3. Using drop-down menu to show content of the pack, while theoretically is possible, is totally not right way to use dropdown menus. Because menus mean that one has to choose something from the list, not just look. And choosing something by clicking means that it will substitute what is currently in the cell or do some other action. You should think of other ideas if you want to show user the content of the package. For example, the most streightforward way to do so would be to make additional column for that with xlookup (vlookup or any other that you like more) function that will return the items per name of the pack in column D as text with punctuation (comas, slashes) from the reference list (column C at sheet "i" from my example).
4. Regarding color highlighting, there are many ways to do so, and it is a separate question. But again, that reference sheet "i" can do much help for this. You can add in column D and E info if the pack needs sizes for caps and t-shirts ("1" for yes, "" for no). Than use conditional formatting with xlookup formula. Alternatively, and simpler you can add new columns at Cust.GiftPackLog sheet with xlookup for this data, hide these columns but use as reference in your conditional formatting.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am new to this and helped me a lot. I could not get your lookup formula to function but it got me onto the right path to learn how to write my own off googling guides. My result was this - =LOOKUP(C46,Values!$M$3:$M$11,Values!$R$3:$R$5) which is pretty much your one. I was then able to adjust that one to work in consecutive cells to make a full sheet better than what i set out to make. Thank you!

Comment: Great to hear it worked out for you. I think that copy-pasting my formula didn't work for you because you forgot to "Change the syntaxes from ";" to ",""
If my response answered your question, please accept the answer with pressing the corresponding button and upvote it.

Comment: PS: If you have office 365 then you can use the new XLOOKUP formula instead, which is a must-know formula that replaces all the LOOKUP, VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP formulas and does much more.